# Using Button and Tab simultaneously?

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-tabactivity

In my app layout I need to have dropdown list button on the top of the screen followed by a tabHost with four tabs, each tab shows different activities.

[image]

and on clicking the Button(Phys) shows you this:

[image]

Now what I want is that the tabcontent changes or updates itself according to the selected subject in the dropdown list.

What I am using is a simple tabactivity.

I want to know any good approach to get this function. Any body who had worked on similar thing Please help me .I desperately need this?

Answer (score 2):

the simple way:

- provide a global static variable such as gCurrentActivity or gSomeValue,
- on every activity set gCurrentActivity, so always you have current activity and that's context
- in many situation you can use getApplicationContext()
- write a method to refresh tab host or other controls after loading any activity or important events

with this simple way you can always update footer, header, tabs and etc.

Answer (score 0):

use a single activity for each tab say, you have 4 tabs say A, B, C, D, E
so Have Five Actiities for each tab AAct, BAct, CAct, DAct, EAct,  I assume each activity have n type of contents, say AaActivity, AbActivity, AcActivity....

have 5 arrays of Class type in a global class

class[] Arr_A = new class[]{AaaCT.class, AvAct.class....};
.......

have 1 flag of integer type in a global class, representing index of content in arrays of activities. say index initialized with 0;

now in onResume method of your activity AAct, BAct, CAct, write...

AAct:

```
onResume()
{
     Intent intent=new Intent(this, ArrA[index]);
     startActivity(intnet);

}
```